# How to allow a third party to develop against a portion of our git tree?

Tags: git

We use git for our project.  We have a contractor who will be working on some of our code, but we want to prevent them from accessing a certain small list of sensitive source files and directories.  My sense of the way to achieve this is to create a fork of our main repo on a new server, and only give the contractor access to this second repo.  Somehow we will exclude the sensitive files/directories from this second repo -- but I need to know how. (One idea we had is to create a branch on the original repo, manually remove these files from the branch, and then fork from only this branch?) Periodically one of our trusted developers will pull all changes from the original repo to the secondary copy, and also periodically they will push changes our contractor made up into the original repo.

Can someone help me determine exactly how to do this?  I want to ensure our security aims are 100% met.

My research has led me to try the following approach. Here's my steps for setup so far, which I hoped were on the right path:

```
# We host our repo on our own server, which we all share access to via SSH.
# On this shared server we keep our git repo under:
#   /git/main-repo.git
cd /git

# make a brand-new repo which will eventually be copied to a new server
# our contractor will be given access to this repo only
git init --bare --shared restricted-repo.git

# now push the old repo (master branch only - he won't need our other branches) into the new empty repo
cd /git/main-repo.git
git push /git/restricted-repo.git 'master:master'

cd  /git/restricted-repo.git
# remove anything to do with our sensitive files.  Assume they start with "sensitive" in their filename
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch src/sensitive*' HEAD

# from my research these cmds seem necessary.  I wonder if it's valid to run the from the bare repo, but 
# git allows this with no errors so I hope it worked.  The commands return almost instantly.
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
git reflog expire --expire=now --all

# this clearly does work, and takes a while
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Now I have two repos, I can clone and work from each, but I do not know how to sync changes between main-repo and restricted-repo.  I tried adding one as a remote of the other and pulling in from the upstream, but that brings in all the branches from the master and also creates merge conflicts when I have edits in both places (even though the edits are on different files).

Answer (score 5):

If part of your repository is managed differently, it should be a different repository.

You can't both remove access to and traces of those files and maintain a common history within a single repository.

Comment: "And you should do sub modules to handle this scenario" http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html

Answer (score 4):

Clone your repo. Don't make it bare as it will limit what you can do with filter-branch.

```
git clone /c/your/path/to/repo
```

go into the repo

```
cd !$:t
```

lose the connection to the repo you cloned from

```
git remote rm origin
```

Create a branch called for-external.

```
git checkout -b for-external
```

Now run git filter-branch to only keep the directories you want to share.

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter path/to/your/project/to/share
```

Clean up

```
git branch | grep -v 'external' | xargs git branch -D
git gc --prune=now
```

Clone this somewhere like unfuddle to give him access to it. Now you can pull in changes that he makes by adding this new unfuddle as a remote to your personal repo.

```
git remote add unfuddle <url to your unfuddle repo>
git push -u unfuddle for-external:integration
```

You can now pull in his changes, and rebase them on top of a branch you use - maybe a new one called "from-external". You can then merge his changes in to your regular branches. This can be done from your regular repo, not the one you initially cloned.

```
git remote add unfuddle <url to your unfuddle repo>
git fetch unfuddle
git branch -t from-consultant unfuddle/integration
```

Don't push to unfuddle from here or you may by accident push a branch that has other info in it. You can create another user and and use a different ssh key to ensure read only access to the unfuddle repo from this repo.

You can use an alternate url in the last remote command that corresponds to a ~/.ssh/config entry which will map it back to the unfuddle url but offering a different key that has the read only restriction.

Now when you `git fetch unfuddle` in your original repository, you can get his latest commits. If you want to contribute work for him, you will need to push from the other repository which will require you to add the remote again - but be careful.

This worked great for me in the past.

Comment: Could I get the exact commands to do this?  For the "clone your repo" step - should this be a bare clone or a working tree clone?

Comment: I've updated the original post with my approach so far.  It's different than the one you proposed, but if you give commands for your approach (or fix mine) I'll be happy to use either one.

Comment: Very useful. It's something I need to set up soon.

Comment: I've tried this.  When I clone the copied repo, I see only the "master" branch, and although the speed of the `git clone` suggests that many files were transferred, I can't seem to find them locally (even after doing a `git checkout integration`

Comment: Also, can you show commands to reconnect to the original repo and pull+merge in the new changes?  I tried this and immediately got back the files I wanted to exclude.

Comment: that was the last set of steps. By connecting to unfuddle, you can fetch from there his changes.

Comment: what do you mean "when I clone the copied repo"? You cloned your own repo, then filterbranched and cleaned this new repo up. You pushed that cleaned branch to unfuddle. Unfuddle now has a repo without your sensitive info. On your original repo, you add a remote which points to unfuddle. When the consultant pushes changes there, you can pull them into your original repo.

Comment: We need to do active development on both repos, and continue to sync our latest changes to him.  Thus the commands I needed help with were how I re-connect our contractor repo with our original repo to pull down our new changes (but sans the sensitive parts -- will I need to purge out the sensitive parts each time?)  Related to that will be how to merge changes from our main repo 'master' branch to our 'for-external' branch (this is surely basic git but I'm quite new)

Comment: You don't restrict your access to unfuddle to be read only. You can now merge, rebase to that branch. Just be careful to not include anything that would introduce a path that you don't want him to see.